# Execute button's command after the animation

Tags: android

In my application i have added a frame-by-frame animation to my button's selector. So, when I press the button the application is started and another activity is launched. The problem is that if I press the button very quickly the application reaches only to the second frame. I would like to launch the next activity after the animation is ended. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button should launch a new Thread instead new Activity directly, and then this new Thread will launch the activity after a few secconds using "Thread.sleep(xxxx);"

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    new Thread()
    {
       public void run()
       {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          //LAUNCH NEW ACTIVITY HERE
       }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this, and it works. But there is another problem. The animation is simulating drawing a circle on the button, the last frame is the whole circle. The animation frames should be visible only after the button is pressed. I've solved this by adding a transparent frame at the start of the frames list. Now, if I press the button the animation is executed and the next activity launched. But if I get back to the previous activity, the button has the last animation frame as the background (the whole circle).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable);` with your delay;

Answer (score 0):

You should set an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to your animation and start another activity on [animation end](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29).

Comment: I don't think that the AnimationListener can be used for the frame by frame animations.